# URLs in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that has an http.get function in it that looks like this:

```
$http.get('api/population_data', {cache: true}).success(function(data) {
$rootScope.population_data = data;
});
```

I am currently in the middle of refactoring my code to put http requests in a service, then call the appropriate function from the service in the controller (makes the app more testable, and follows better design practices):

```
DashboardHTTPService.get_population_data().then(
function(response) {
$rootScope.population_data = response;
});
```

My issue is that when I make the .get_population_data call, the service no longer resolves the full url in the http.get request: What I'm trying to say is, when I had the http.get request in my dashboard controller, I could make the request from there and it would know to navigate to my api url '/dashboard/4/api/population_data', but when I make the http.get() from the function in the service it just looks for /api/population_data (does not prepend the /dashboard/4 like before).

I think there is something about url resolution in the context of the controller that I am missing...can someone explain why this is? I'm thinking I can have the controller pass in the location.pathname to the service, but I don't think that is the best solution...

Thanks, sorry for being a bit confused, but I didn't think that any of the other questions I looked at answered my question appropirately..

Comment: Are you using $location (or router) in html5 mode (ie with no ``#`` in the location)?

Comment: your request is done with a relative path, so, unless you set a ``base`` path in your html ``head``, that path will be concatenated to the current url. My bet is your issue has nothing to do with service or controller, but everything to do with the current url in your location bar.

Comment: i do have a # in the url.

Comment: before or after ``/dashboard/4`` ?

Comment: after. /dashboard/4/#/api/info

Comment: Are you sure you didn't put '/api/population_data' (starting with a slash) in your service?

Comment: I did put it in my service, which is why i'm confused...on my localhost the URL that it is trying to perform the get request on is /api/population_data, not /dashboard/4/api/population_data...

Comment: yes it was starting with a slash...

Comment: I realize that was a mistake...derp

Comment: if you put an path with a ``/`` (absolute path) at the beginning, the browser will replace the whole path with your url. Therefore, navigating to ``/foo/bar`` from ``http://example.com/baz`` will result in ``http://example.com/foo/bar``. On the other hand, navigating to ``foo/bar`` (relative path) will result in ``http://example.com/baz/foo/bar``.